# aggregation breaks encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation, aggregation

I have been reading books trying to understand the various aspects of aggregation and composition.However I came across a point where I felt like aggregation can enhance loose coupling but can also break encapsulation.

Enhance loose coupling.

```
public class Car{
    private Engine engine;
    Car(Engine e){
        this.engine=e;
    }
}
```

In above any implementation of Engine class can be created and pushed to Car object at the time of creation, and since the Engine instance can live without car thus it is a perfect example of aggregation. ( this example may not be a great realworld example , but I think I made my point)

Now the client code has the full control over the Engine Object, thus it can change few states of the engine object passed to the Car,And Car's implementation would break the encapsulation since its object or state ( which is Engine) is no more has the right integrity in the Car.

is my understanding correct ?

Comment: It kind of depends with encapsulation you dont want to ever change the state of an object rather you want to operate the object. So with engine instead of engine.setOn(boolean) you have engine.turnOn(). If you only want the car to be able to operate on the engine then in the constructor you would clone the object to restrict access. this.engine = (Engine)e.clone(); other operations on the car could be removeEngine then you could access the engine but the car no longer has one.

Comment: IMO, I don't think the client has the control over the Engine object. I would imagine there to be a higher level class called Manufacturer that would create the correct Engine object and set that as the engine for a particular Car object.

Comment: I think what he is referring to is that the process that creates the car would have a reference to the engine when it shouldn't have.

Comment: @Vaibhav, I agree a properly designed class should be like perhaps you said, But The manufacturer In this case becomes the client , and he simply can modify some state of the Engine object just after the Car is created, and then the car object would render broken. DOn't you think so ?

Comment: @BevynQ, I would then imagine the entire Engine class is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Engine` can be broken by `Car` only if it is mutable, i.e. car can change engine's state. However you can either define immutable class `Engine` (that has only getters to access state and business methods that do not change state) or create interface `Engine` implemented by class `EngineImpl`. `EngineImpl` is not immutable. It includes functionality that can change its state. However it implements interface `Engine` that exposes only "immutable" methods towards client. So, car cannot change state of `EngineImpl` hidden behind read-only interface `Engine`. In this case the encapsulation is not broken.

You are right: that this is not the real-world example: in real world driver controls engine via interface provided by his car and can break the engine :(

Comment: Agreed, +1 for you. Just one doubt, very trivial , a mutable implementation will break the Car , not the Engine , right ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, loose coupling is targeting the relationship between Car & Engine.

Though the car accepts any Engine through its Constructor, I believe, the Car won't expose the Engine by a getter Method.

This Constructor should be having proper access control / level and be used by a factory or other creational pattern which takes care of integrating an Engine with Car.

Allowing the Car's client to get access to the Engine should be through Car's interface.

Comment: I think you missed my point, Let me Put it this way.
Engine e = new EngineImpl();
Car c = new Car(e);

e.setSomethingOnEngine();// This may break cars behavior

Comment: e.setSomethingOnEngine() won't be usually done by any factory or creational pattern. Maybe, Builder can build the engine, but it won't alter the engine after it is created and given for injecting it into the Car. If its does, then the creational pattern code is violating the principles.